# Python dictionary stored in MySQL as Text

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dictionary

I have a column in a MySQL Database where Python dictionaries are stored as text.

Input:

```
print(row.optional_items)
print(type(optional_items))
```

Output:

```
{'Bed 90,-': '90,00', 'Baby bath': '90,00', 'Child chair': '90,00', 'Fee': '150,00', 'End cleaning'
: '730,00', 'Linned Kr. 90,-': '90,00'}
<class 'str'>
```

I would like to work with the variable as a Python dictionary but it is not possible because Python considers it a string. I've tried converting it to a dict by using `dict(row.feline_optional_items)` but it returns `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Is there a way to convert row.optional_items to a dictionary so I can work with it?

I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: If you have any control over what's stored in the column, it's probably much better to store this data as JSON, because it's a standard format and other languages can easily read the data too.

Comment: It would be even better to normalize the database, and store each dictionary element in a separate row, using an attribute-value table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert a dict in string form to an actual dict, do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
dict_str = "{'a': 1}"
dict_dict = literal_eval(dict_str)
```

Comment: You should emphasize the use of literal_eval() over eval() since eval() is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!